Harris recurrence of the Langevin diffusion
I am currently trying to understand the following proof:
Under the assuption that $\nabla\log\pi (L_t)$ is continuously differentiable, the measure $\pi$ is invariant and $\parallel P^t_L(x,\cdot)-\pi\parallel\rightarrow 0 \forall x\in X.$ Here L denotes the Langevin diffusion ($dL_t= \frac{1}{2}\nabla\log\pi (L_t) +dW_t$).
In the paper Exponential convergence of Langevin diffusions and their discrete approximation from Roberts and Tweedie the convergence is proven as follows:
Since the process has a stationary distribution it is at least recurrent. This extends to Harris recurrence  due to the continuous sample paths. Then we have positive Harris recurrence and because of theorem 6.1 in Meyn and Tweedie.
Theorem 6.1 states that the convergence from above holds for a positive Harris recurrent chain with invariant probability $\pi$  iff there exists an irreducibe skeleton chain.
I only need  help with the convergence part. Here are my thoughts for the proof.
I think the condition of the irreducible skeleton chain is fullfilled as it is  known that the Langevin diffusion is irreducible and hence there also exists some irreducible skeleton chain. Therefore, I only have to proof the Harris recurrence. For that I want to ensure recurrence first.
I think that recurrence holds because every irreducible chain is either transient or recurrent.  Since we have invariance our chain can not be transient and is thus recurrent.
I also think that the sample paths are continuous as it is known that brownian motion has continuous sample paths and additionally we assumed that $\nabla\log\pi (L_t)$ is continuously differentiable. 
My questions are now:
1)Are my thoughts from above correct?
2)Why do recurrence and continuous sample paths imply positive Harris recurrence?
